# finding the dim names of item in multidimensional array

Tags: r

I have not done much with multidimensional arrays in r, so this may be a easy question-
I am trying to find a simple way to find the dimension names for an individual item within a multidimensional array:

```
my.array <- array(32:56, dim=c(3,4,2))
dimnames(my.array)=list(c("a","b","c"), c("1","2", "3", "4"),c("y","n"))
which(my.array==33)
>2
```

I know that the second item in this array matches this criteria, but how can I easily find out what are its dim labels related to this item (i.e., my.array["b", "1", "y"]=33)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for `arr.ind`:

```
X1 <- which(my.array==33, arr.ind=TRUE)
X1
#   dim1 dim2 dim3
# b    2    1    1
my.array[X1]
# [1] 33
my.array[2, 1, 1]
# [1] 33
mapply("[", dimnames(my.array), X1)
# [1] "b" "1" "y"
```